# Where to put controllers of main application in cakephp when theme is used as plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

I new to cakephp, i have created plugin of theme named Amuk

[image]

Now i want to do my application coding, i have doubt regarding where i have to put application controller, in the main src folder or in the /plugins/Amuk/src/Controller/. Second doubt is where i will put my view file. Here i have created default.ctp inside Layout folder, but where shouls i put my other views that are to be rendered inside this default view. Please help to clear my doubts or give up some usefull links to start with. I am using Latest Version of Cakephp.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of Cake, you shouldn't be tagging this question with 2.0 and 2.3. It's on 3.5 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for naming files in a plugin is the same as for the main application. Your controllers go in the Controller folder, e.g. `Controller/ThingsController.php`. Your templates go in a folder under Templates, named the same as the controller, so `Template/Things/index.ctp` for example. See [Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) and [Folder Structure](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html) in the manual for more complete details.

But the easiest thing to do might be to use the bake tool (e.g. `bin/cake bake -p Amuk`) to have it generate skeleton code for you. It will put all the files in the right places, correctly named, with correct namespaces, generate inputs in the edit page based on fields it finds in the database, lots of useful stuff. Anything it generates that you don't need, just delete. See [Code Generation with Bake](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks Greg. One thing i want to clear my doubt is for eg. i have created plugin for Theme so for LoginController should i create it in main controller or inside plugin controller, i think it should be in main controller and all the view files should be in Theme plugin.

Comment: It would typically be a UsersController with a login action, not a LoginController. I think that you have the arrangement right (there "should" perhaps be a default login.ctp in your main application and then an override in the plugin), but a plugin theme is something I haven't done yet in Cake3.